# ItemizedOverlay open source - why did they synchronized the overlayItem on the draw method?

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

This code snippet is taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/mapsforge/org/mapsforge/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.java.htm):

```
  protected void drawOverlayBitmap(Canvas canvas, Point drawPosition, Projection projection,
      byte drawZoomLevel) {
    synchronized (this.visibleItems) {
      // erase the list of visible items
      this.visibleItems.clear();

      this.numberOfItems = size();
      if (this.numberOfItems < 1) {
        // no items to draw
        return;
      }

      // draw the overlay items
      for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < this.numberOfItems; ++itemIndex) {
        // get the current item
        this.overlayItem = createItem(itemIndex);

        synchronized (this.overlayItem) {
          // check if the item has a position
          if (this.overlayItem.getPoint() == null) {
            continue;
          }

          // make sure that the cached item position is valid
          if (drawZoomLevel != this.overlayItem.cachedZoomLevel) {
            this.overlayItem.cachedMapPosition = projection.toPoint(
                this.overlayItem.getPoint(),
                this.overlayItem.cachedMapPosition, drawZoomLevel);
            this.overlayItem.cachedZoomLevel = drawZoomLevel;
          }

          // calculate the relative item position on the display
          this.itemPosition.x = this.overlayItem.cachedMapPosition.x - drawPosition.x;
          this.itemPosition.y = this.overlayItem.cachedMapPosition.y - drawPosition.y;

          // get the correct marker for the item
          if (this.overlayItem.getMarker() == null) {
            if (this.defaultMarker == null) {
              // no marker to draw the item
              continue;
            }
            this.itemMarker = this.defaultMarker;
          } else {
            this.itemMarker = this.overlayItem.getMarker();
          }

          // get the position of the marker
          this.markerBounds = this.itemMarker.copyBounds();

          // calculate the bounding box of the marker
          this.left = this.itemPosition.x + this.markerBounds.left;
          this.right = this.itemPosition.x + this.markerBounds.right;
          this.top = this.itemPosition.y + this.markerBounds.top;
          this.bottom = this.itemPosition.y + this.markerBounds.bottom;

          // check if the bounding box of the marker intersects with the canvas
          if (this.right >= 0 && this.left <= canvas.getWidth() && this.bottom >= 0
              && this.top <= canvas.getHeight()) {
            // set the position of the marker
            this.itemMarker.setBounds(this.left, this.top, this.right, this.bottom);

            // draw the item marker on the canvas
            this.itemMarker.draw(canvas);

            // restore the position of the marker
            this.itemMarker.setBounds(this.markerBounds);

            // add the current item index to the list of visible items
            this.visibleItems.add(Integer.valueOf(itemIndex));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

now what that i find hard to get is why did they synchronized overlayItem, it makes no sense to me, there are several reasons why i think its redundent, on top of those is the fact that within the sync block, there is a refrence to a final member of the OverlayItem class which is the GeoPoint, so what sense does it make to think other threads could change this?!

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

An object market final marks an object as a constant, for example having:

```
final ArrayList<Integer> visibleItems;
```

As a result you are not allowed to assign another object to the `visibleItems`, because `visibleItems` is marked `final`:

For example trying to do like in the code below, will result in a compilation error:

```
ArrayList<Integer> anotherArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
visibleItems = anotherArray; //Compile error.
```

However, this does not mean that all the elements the array list contains, are also marked as `final`. No.

One thread may add new elementes, onother may remove some elements:

```
anotherArray.add(2);
anotherArray.add(5);
//........

anotherArray.remove(5);
```

That is why the variable is kept `syncronized`, to assure no more than 1 thread can update the content of the array list simulaniously.

Comment: this is NOT the case,         check : synchronized (this.overlayItem) {
          // check if the item has a position
          if (this.overlayItem.getPoint() == null) {
            continue;
          }

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood the question. I was focused on `this.visibleItems` rather on `this.overlayItem.`. Sorry.

Comment: Anyway, what I said remains valid for this case too. I don't know what methods contains the `Item` class, but let assume it has a method called: `setItem()`. And again, 2 threads will be able to call `overlayItem.setItem()`. The `final` keyword only specify that you can not asign another item to `overlayItem`, for example: `overlayItem = anotherItem` = compilation error. Do not confuse `final` with `synchronized`, they both have different purposes.

Comment: then you should read this : http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/mapsforge/org/mapsforge/android/maps/OverlayItem.java.htm and see that everything is final, except for the marker, which is the only thing you need to synchronize on an item for modifing